# Eigenfunctions heuristics for self-conjugate priors

Tags: bayesian, references, conjugate-prior

**Previously asked on** [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068690/eigenfunctions-heuristics-for-self-conjugate-priors?noredirect=1#comment6360351_3068690).

I am looking for a citable reference (books, research papers, PhD theses, *not* websites, internal reports, etc.) about the heuristic interpretation of self-conjugate priors as "eigenfunctions for the conditioning operator".
This is best explained (though without reference) in the Wikipedia page [Conjugate prior#Interpretations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Analogy_with_eigenfunctions[citation_needed]).

In a nutshell: A *statistical model* is any family $\{P_\theta\}_\theta$ of probability distributions, parametrized by $\theta\in T$ (e.g., $T\subset \mathbb R$ or $T\subset \mathbb R^k$).
Some data $X:=(X_1,\dotsc, X_k)$ is sampled from the model in two stages:

- firstly, we let $\Theta\in T$ be a $Q$-distributed random variable;
- secondly, we draw $X_1,\dotsc, X_k$ in such a way that $X_1,\dotsc, X_k\mid \Theta\sim P_\Theta$ conditionally i.i.d..

The *posterior distribution of $Q$ given $X$* is then defined as $Q^X:=Q[\Theta\in \cdot\mid X]$.

A family of distributions $\{Q_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ (again $A\subset \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^k$) is *self-conjugate* (for a fixed model) if the posterior distribution $Q_\alpha^X$ satisfies $Q_\alpha^X=Q_{\alpha'}$ for some $\alpha'\in A$.

Heuristically, $Q_\alpha$ is (sort of) an "eigenfunction" for the conditioning operator $\mathbf E[\cdot \mid X]$.

Comment: The same question was asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383270/operator-theoretic-perspectives-on-bayesian-inference) (No answer)

Comment: I appreciate your linking to your question on [math.SE]. Nonetheless, it is better not to cross post at all. Just pick the site where you want to ask & ask there.

Comment: @gung In principle I agree. I came to the unfortunate decision of cross-posting after (wrongly) requiring moderators' intervention on math.stackexchange. In any case, as kindly pointed out by yourself and kjetil b halvorsen, the question is a duplicate. I apologize for all these inconveniences.

Comment: No problem, @AlephBeth. There are a lot of cultural nuances of the SE system, & they also vary site by site to some degree. I certainly don't question your good faith here.